# Pycharm annoyingly highlighting forward type hints

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, syntax-highlighting

(Hope this is on topic here, please suggest another forum if not!)

When I use a forward type hint in Python, PyCharm highlights this in the same color as a selected (ie. left-clicked) token:

[image: Python code with a forwarded type hint highlighted in olive]

However, it is not actually selected - I can select another symbol, and then both are highlighted in the same color.   Since you can't see it here because of brevity, let me add: the type shown is certainly /resolving/ - if I use an bogus or otherwise unresolvable type, I get a different color that is the same as the unresolved non-forward type hint color.

How can I disable this behavior / make forward type hints get treated like regular type hints visually?   It's jarring and distracting, all the worse because I want to actually use select highlighting sometimes.

I can't find any class in the Editor settings that has a green background besides the selection.   Literally nothing is olive-background color based on syntax.